# tomcat 7, application is running but unreachable

Tags: java, tomcat, http-status-code-404

I have a java application that is running on tomcat7 (OS is Ubuntu LTS, I downloaded tomcat from the repositories, not the website).
I go to the tomcat application manager, I deploy my *.war file, then I see the application running, with no problem or error messages, but if I go to the url:

```
127.0.0.1:8080/myApplicationName
```

I get:

```
404 - The requested resource is not avaible
```

Did I miss something?

Edit: as suggested here are some of the tomcat logs

localhost_access_log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Nov/2014:14:43:12 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1894
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Nov/2014:14:43:12 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 991
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Nov/2014:14:43:17 +0100] "GET /myApp HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Nov/2014:14:43:17 +0100] "GET /myApp/ HTTP/1.1" 404 977
```

Comment: Where did you deploy the .war file? Did you setup the URL in the manager?

Comment: Tomcat seems to be running fine - it's giving you a `404`. You just have nothing at path `/` in the application.

Comment: So, I deploy the application via application manager. I can see it in the /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps folder, both myApp.war and the folder myApp.

I did not touch any of the configuration file but tomcat-user.xml !

Comment: check the log files.  it will tell you why you're getting a 404.  it could be a misconfigured web.xml, a missing file, a context binding that differs from the application war-file name, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The problem was that I zipped the entire folder of my project, and for some reason tomcat did not like that.
I tried to zip the content of the folder and everything is working fine!